# How to expose a JS Node Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am diving into Node.js and have had success installing express and socket. I was able to make the basic chat program easily. This requires these steps:

In app.js (my Node server)

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

I included minified socket.io.js file in public/javascripts

In public/javascripts/testchat.js simply call IO like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

Then do whatever you want with IO stuff.

---

I've made my own Node.js module but I don't understand how to expose it.

In node_modules/myModule/index.js

```
module.exports = require('./lib');
```

In node_modules/myModule/lib/index.js

```
module.exports = myModule;

function myModule(){
    this.name = "hello";
}

myModule.prototype.test = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

I can call this stuff easily in app.js

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var myMod = new myModule.test(); //hello
```

But I don't want this thing to run every time I start the server. I want to to only run when a user accesses a specific page. How do I get from here to there? I know I am missing something... I was expecting to be able to do this:

In public/javascripts/myModule.js

```
var myModule = myModule(); //myModule is undefined
myModule.test();
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's `app.js`? Is that your Node.js server?

The variables that are available to you in your Node server won't be available in your client-facing JavaScript. They don't share the same scope. However, you can look into using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), a JS pre-compiler, to also `require` myModule in your client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Yes it is my Node server. How then does socket do it? It does not user browserfy. My module will somewhat be a client-server relationship so I am think following socket's formula would work for me.

Comment: Ok. I've never used socket.io, unfortunately, so I'll have to let somebody else answer this one then.

Comment: Are you trying to expose your server side module to the browser? If so, as far as I know, its not possible in any way. What socket.io allows you to do is push/emit data from the server to the client at will. Traditionally, a client requests a page/data and the server responds to that request. With socket.io communication is 2-way but it is strictly for data(of any type)

Comment: Well let's say my module built a random bejewled game grid (or something). I don't want the user to have any control over it, I want it all generated on the server. But the public JS page should be able to request a new game grid, shouldn't it? Maybe I am seeing this the wrong way.

Comment: I was VERY wrong. You can actually call node.js modules from DOM. http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/09/10/node-webkit.html

Comment: For example, you can have a button that sends a request to '/new_game'. With the express and canvas module, you can do:
`app.get('/new_game', function(req, res) {
      //create new game and canvas code here
     //stream game data here}
http://thechangelog.com/node-canvas-render-and-stream-html5-canvas-using-node-js/

Comment: Let's say the game has lots of animations, or redraws, etc. Wouldn't it be really awful to have the server draw the canvas and then send it to the browser? That could be insane amounts of bandwidth (like watching a live stream). Isn't it better to have the client do all the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can request info through socket.io. It tends to be a bit resource intensive to hold the network connection open. Typically, most of the games and apps that we write, either for a mobile app or a web site, call REST APIs that we have written in Express, which is a node.js framework. Essentially you create endpoints that respond to HTTP calls. They send back whatever you want, we normally use JSON to respond with the data. So, you would need to create a RESTful api app, and behind one of the APIs would your module. You call the API with whatever parameters from your web page, and the app responds with your data.

Then of course you need to get into authentication, so only the people you want to have access get it. You've got security and scaling issues. It's a new world.

Comment: resource intensive for whom?

Comment: Resource intensive on the server. You're holding the network connection. On the other hand, you're not creating or tearing down connections continuously, so it's probably easier on the client. If you really need fast response times, at the potential cost of consuming more servers, then it's probably a better solution.